# Как склоняется слово "Нод(а)"

Tags: склонение

Нода - это заимствование от слова node (узел). Из [викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), узнал, что это слово женского рода. Используется в компьютерных приложениях для обозначения блока программы, который соединяется с другими нодами и образует сложную структуру:

[image]

Так-же используется для обозначения компьютера в специфических сетях

Кое-что очевидно и используется повсеместно:

> Нодовый редактор
>
> Ноды
>
> Группа нодов

Кое-что неочевидно, и примеров использования не найти. Например, каким образом склонять это слово, особенно во фразах:

> Использовать активную нод(у)
>
> Выделенных нод(ов)
>
> Цвет ноды(?)
>
> Добавить к ноде(у)

Точно ли это слово женского рода?

Есть варианты как с мужского рода:

> Исправляем это недоразумение используя нод Hue/Saturation/Value.

https://pikabu.ru/story/vozmozhnosti_sovremennoy_kompyuternoy_grafiki_4291152

так и женского:

> Нода Copy. Наследование трансформаций и атрибутов. Техника Copy
> Stamping.

http://vfxlaboratory.ru/kurs/houdini-artist-101

Comment: Слова женского рода, заканчивающиеся на -а, склоняются по первому типу склонения.

Comment: никогда не сталкивался с формой этого слова в женском роде, из последнего словосочетания первой группы очевидно, что оно мужского рода, именно в нём оно зафиксировано и в [Мультитране](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=node), возможно женский род - это сленговая форма, типа **тулза, фича**

Comment: Кстати, а за что минус? Нормальный вопрос вроде.

Comment: сейчас есть специальный сайт SE для вопросов о русском языке на русском языке: https://rus.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @qdinar ух, я думал, тут только этот... мне удалить этот вопрос или оставить?

Comment: @Crantisz поищите и спросите в http://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @qdinar не вводите, пожалуйста, в заблуждение - в комьюнити приветствуются вопрос и на русском и на английском.

Comment: @qdinar в пользу этого сайта еще свидетельствует то, что этот вопрос по сути является вопросом о переводе с английского.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вариативность по роду - довольно распространенное явление, особенно среди заимствованных слов: компонент/компонента, метод/метода, вольер/вольера и др.

Какой бы род вы ни выбрали, старайтесь придерживаться его, хотя бы в рамках одного документа, т.е.

- либо один нод, 2 нода, 5 нодов,
- либо одна нода, 2 ноды, 5 нод.

А еще есть вполне годное русское слово **узел**, у которого нет проблем с родом и склонением.

Answer (score 3):

Слово "нода" было заимствовано относительно недавно, так что я не думаю, что есть какой-то стандарт его употребления. Не могу сказать ничего про мужской род - сколько ни работаю в ИТ, видел только употребления в женском роде. Например, вопрос на ruSO (первое, что в гугле попалось):

> [Jenkins — два билда на одной ноде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683396/180398)
>   Возможно ли в Jenkins делать два билда одного одинакового проекта на одной ноде одновременно?

Comment: тот факт что нода соседствует с билдом может свидетельствовать в пользу его жаргонности